# Random variable and CDF

Tags: probability

5 people randomly select a number from 1 to 10. Value of random variable X is the largest number chosen. Calculate $F_X(5.5)$ and $P(X=5)$. Answers are: $\frac{1}{32}, 0.2101$.

I solved this part in this way:
$F_X(5.5) = P(X<5.5)$
It is the same as probability that every one chooses a number that is less than 5.5, so it is simply equal to $\frac{1}{32}$

My attempt to solve the second part using CDF was this:
$P(X=5) = P(X\leq6) - P(X\leq5) = (\frac{6}{10})^5 - (\frac{5}{10})^5 = 0.04651$
It probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: First part is correct. In the second part, you calculated $P(X=6)$. You have $P(X=5)=P(X\le 5)-P(X\le 4)$.

Comment: The answer for the second part should be 0.02101 instead of 0.2101.